# IIS 7.5 MVC3 Speed Issues

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I am seeing speed issues with my MVC3 application. For testing purposes I created a blank MVC3 application and loaded it into IIS 7.5. The first time I go to the site it takes anywhere between 6 -15 seconds to load the page. I have tried the following link and it does not help.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

I enabled everything as that post says, IIS comes up just fine. But still I have the same issues. I go to the site the first time and it's very slow to respond. After that it's very quick. Then if I leave it alone for about 30 minutes and go back - it's slow again.

The idle timeout does not seem to do anything either if I set it to 0.

Comment: Are you aware of how ASP works and that it's _compiled_ (which is precisely what the first visit is doing, loading it in to IIS's cache)? You can change the recycle time of the AppPool to re-use the next load time (forcing it to stay in memory longer) if that's what you're after...

Comment: This is about the worker processes on IIS shutting down your site due to inactivity. You can set the idle timeout to zero to stop this happening.

Comment: Without any data about your IIS7 environment, CPU, Memory, Load, Disk I/O etc this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Just becuase you do not have an answer does not mean it's not a 'real question'.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the application pool worker process is shutting down due to inactivity (no incoming requests in the past x-minutes).  I don't think this is the typical *set-it-to-zero-for-infinite* type parameter.

There are a few options.  You can just raise that timeout value (in the Application Pool settings, it's the **Idle Time-out(minutes)** value).  You could also get an application to hit the web application, in essence keeping the worker process and application pool from shutting down due to being idle.

Comment: I once did the keep-alive from a Linux server by running a cron job every x minutes that issued the wget command to the index page.

Answer (score 1):

Check this post for **Auto-Start** feature in **IIS 7.5**

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

> The new "auto start" feature of ASP.NET 4 and IIS 7.5 provides a
>   well-defined approach that allows you to perform expensive application
>   startup and pre-cache logic that can run before any end-users hit your
>   application.  This enables you to have your application "warmed up"
>   and ready from the very beginning, and deliver a consistent high
>   performance experience.

Comment: As I stated in my question I tried this. It did not give any performance increase.

Comment: I think that just has to do when IIS/AppPool starts up.  It'll still timeout with inactivity.